# upload a file using jsr223 sampler getting failure on JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Trying to upload a image file using JSR223 sampler using the following code, getting 200 status code but expecting `202:Accepted`, what I am missing here ?

Code:

```
    def storageProtocol = "https";
    def storageServer = "qatestserver.com"
    def newImageFilePath = vars.get('filePathUUIDA_' + ((vars.get('__jm__namespace_iterator__idx') as int) + 1));
    def imageFilePath = newImageFilePath.toString();
    def sampleFilePath = imageFilePath.replace("\\\\","\\\\\\\\");
    
    def RequestConfig uploadRequestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
      .setConnectTimeout(30000)
      .setSocketTimeout(30000)
      .build();
    def uploadUriBuilder = new URIBuilder().setScheme(storageProtocol)
      .setHost(storageServer);
    
    def URI uri = uploadUriBuilder.setPath("/api/v3/storage/namespace/" + "${namespaceid}" + "/image")
      .setParameter("sid", "${sid_value}")
      .setParameter("test_uid", "${test_code}")
      .setParameter("image_uid", "${imageuuid}")
      .build();
    
    def RequestBuilder requestBuilder = RequestBuilder.create("POST")
      .setConfig(uploadRequestConfig)
      .setUri(uri)
      .setHeader("X-AmbraHealth-SID", "${sid_value}")
      .setHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
      .setHeader("X-DicomGrid-Client", "USER")
      .setHeader("X-DicomGrid-Version", "3.22.5.0")
      .setHeader("X-File-Name", "555210_98168_98980_0.img")
      .setHeader("Referer", "https://qatestserver.com/load.html?namespace=${namespaceid}")
      .setHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/dicom");
    
    def InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(sampleFilePath));
    log.info("Entity Value : "+ entity +" Sample File Path : " +sampleFilePath);
    requestBuilder.setEntity(entity);
<Code for post call>
```

Am getting :

```
2023-07-16 20:05:01,903 INFO o.a.j.p.j.s.J.ImageUpload: Entity Value : [Chunked: false]  Sample File Path : C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_0.img;
```

What does `[Chunked: false]` means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what you're "missing" here because we don't know how the server side handles the file upload event, you need to share your API contract as well so we could either reproduce the issue or assume what could be wrong.

I can only suggest considering using [MultipartEntity](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/current/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html) instead of InputStreamEntity. Check out [Multipart Upload with Apache HttpClient](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-multipart-upload) article for more details.

Also it might be the case you don't need to do any scripting at all, JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler is capable of uploading the files.

[image]

You can even record the call using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html), just copy the file(s) you are going to upload to JMeter's "bin" folder before recording. See [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload and Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing) article for more details.

[Chunked encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding) is a form of data transfer when the total size is now known and the transfer is being handled in parts (chunks)